# Circular references error when pulling JSON entities in EF Core

Tags: json, .net-core, entity-framework-core

My Entities:

```
public partial class Student: IBrand
    {
        public Student()
        {
            Grades = new HashSet<Grade>();

        }
        [Key]

        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Users")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public  ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Parent")]
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }

        public Parent Parent { get; set; }
        public int? SectionId { get; set; }
        public string FatherName { get; set; }
        public int classNumber { get; set; }
        public Section Section { get; set; }
        public string brevetResult { get; set; }
        public DateTime? dateLeftAec { get; set; }
        public string additionalInfo { get; set; }
        public bool bacc { get; set; }
        public string baccResult { get; set; }
        public string baccSection { get; set; }
        public int BrandId { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public Brand Brand { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<StudentRegistration> StudentReg { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Absence> Absences { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<StudentStudyYear> StudentStudyYears { get; set; }

    }
public class Grade: IBrand
    {


        public int gradeId { get; set; }
        public int grade { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public int SubjectId { get; set; }
        public int TeacherId { get; set; }
        public int TermId { get; set; }
        public int SectionId { get; set; }
        public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
        public string ResultToEdit { get; set; }

        public bool IsEditedByAdmin { get; set; }
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
        public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
        public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
        public virtual Term Term { get; set; }
        public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
        public int BrandId { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]

        public Brand Brand { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<GradeStudyYear> GradeStudyYears { get; set; }

}
```

I'm trying to get a student with his grades, but I encountered a problem with circular references. I tried to add this to the startup file:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
```

That *seemed* to solve the circular references problem, but then I started getting 5GB worth of data... so that code apparently just suppressed the error without solving the circular data problem.

I tried to put the attribute [JSONIgnore] in my grade.cs file, but I need to get a student from grade so it will not be useful.

How can I solve this circular references problem?

Comment: I would recommend not serializing your EF models, and instead use a flat DTO object instead.  JSON doesn't inheritly have a way of dealing with object references, so you need to handle them yourself (or have another library do it for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serializing entities leads to a number of issues and exposes more information about your domain than is needed. When returning data to a view or an API consumer you can instead define a view model or DTO to contain just the details that consumer will need in whatever structure best serves that need. This avoids reference issues which EF navigation properties can cause, reduces the amount of domain knowledge and data you expose to clients, and minimizes the payload size to just what is needed. Data can be flattened, so if you are displaying a list of one entity, you don't need a ViewModel/DTO per related entity, your view model can merely contain relevant details of any related entity that applies to that consumer.

Once you have defined your view model / DTO you can use `.Select()` to populate it, or set up mapping with Automapper and populate it using `.ProjectTo<TViewModel>()`.